# What will happen if the program will substitute jar files on the run?

Tags: java, jar

What will happen if the program will substitute jar files on the run?

Program execution sequence is the next:

1. Test application execution is started under TestNG FW.
2. jar-files of application under test are downloaded and updated (old files replaced by new) in `...\build-under-test\` folder (need to test the latest build)
3. Application under test is started from test application.

As you see Test application and Application under test are executed in the same JVM. So the question is: is it ok for the application to update it's own library files (this files are actually used only on th 3rd step)? (will it crach, use cached jar file on step 1 or ...???)

Comment: Have you tried? Usually, if the JARs are on the classpath, you will not be able to overwrite them, as they are in use and locked. The error message will depend on your OS.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht, I am just going to do this

Answer (score 0):

No, we can not do this.

There is an error `File is already in use`

Comment: You need to use a custom ClassLoader, which is able to reload JAR files...

Comment: @Ben, i am going to try another way - update files before starting Test application